# Merged ResourceDictionary initalization in UWP app

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, resourcedictionary

During development of my UWP app I have noticed and intersting oddity which I have hard time explaining.

I user MvvmLight and I decided to add the ViewModelLocator resource instance in a separate ResourceDictionary *Core.xaml* which will be referenced from `MergedDictionaries` in *App.xaml*.
Following is the content of *App.xaml*:

```
<Application ...>
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Core.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Converters.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Contents of *Core.xaml*:

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
    <viewModel:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now I supposed the resources in *Core.xaml* are initialized during the `InitializeComponent` method call in *App.xaml.cs*, but when I tried to use the `ServiceLocator` class (which is set in the constructor of ViewModelLocator in MvvmLight) - like this - `ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<INavigationService>().Navigate<MainViewModel>();` - I get an exception saying:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: ServiceLocationProvider must be set.
```

Indeed, if I put an breakpoint in the constructor of ViewModelLocator, it is not called before the Window is activated. More interestingly still - if I manually reference the *Locator* resource key (for example putting `Debug.WriteLine(Resources["Locator"]);` above the call of `ServiceLocator`), everything works fine. The same goes if I move the `ViewModelLocator` resource directly to App.xaml - then it is instantiated during `IntializeComponent`.

Is there a lazy instantiation of merged resource dictionaries in UWP apps? Or why does it behave this way?

Comment: I noticed that this strange behavior occurs when you have several normal (not styles) objects in your ResourceDictionary. Having just one ViewModelLocator completely works and ctor is being called. My findings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466035/uwp-resourcedictionary-is-not-being-loaded-when-i-add-a-second-object-to-it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `ResourceDictionary` in UWP doesn't have any code behind (no `InitializeComponent`). Therefore, any class references defined in a `ResourceDictionary` won't be initialized directly.

Neither does the `App.InitializeComponent` do this for you. Resource dictionaries in UWP just don't provide this functionallity - don't ask me why.

You can easily try this by trying to initialize a `DataTemplate` in a `ResourceDictionary`.
This should - sadly - neither work.

However, using the `Resources["Locator"]` access in code behind triggers the constructor of the class and you're fine.

This ain't be a solution, but a explanation of your problem.
I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! One way to circumvent this problem could be adding a code-behind class for the dictionary, like you do with dictionaries containing {x:Bind}, right? But I guess it is better to instantiate the ViewModelLocator manually, as this is the only resource needed directly, so it saves memory on load time.

Comment: @MZetko If it's something very central, you might initialize it in the `App.xaml` `Resources` section instead.